# How to Open Android System Settings from Unity Android App

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I am trying to open the System Settings from my Unity Android app, but I am receiving the following error:

> UnityEngine.AndroidJavaException:
>   android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle
>   Intent {act =android.settings.ACTION_SETTINGS
>   cat=[android.intent.category.DEFAULT] dat=package:com.xxx.xxxxx
>   flg=0x10000000}

Here is my code:

```cs
try
{
    using (var unityClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer"))
    using (AndroidJavaObject currentActivityObject = unityClass.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity"))
    {
        string packageName = currentActivityObject.Call<string>("getPackageName");

        using (var uriClass = new AndroidJavaClass("android.net.Uri"))
        using (AndroidJavaObject uriObject = uriClass.CallStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("fromParts", "package", packageName, null))
        using (var intentObject = new AndroidJavaObject("android.content.Intent", "android.settings.ACTION_SETTINGS", uriObject))
        {
            intentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("addCategory", "android.intent.category.DEFAULT");
            intentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("setFlags", 0x10000000);
            currentActivityObject.Call("startActivity", intentObject);
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Debug.Log(e);
}
```

Comment: Do you get any error messages? If not you can start by exporting your project to gradle and load it to Android Studio and debug it from there to catch any native errors.

Comment: @S.Fragkos, I am getting this Exception,

UnityEngine.AndroidJavaException: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent {act =android.settings.ACTION_SETTINGS cat=[android.intent.category.DEFAULT] dat=package:com.xxx.xxxxx flg=0x10000000}.............

Answer (score 3):

This works for me on Android 10

before: android.intent.category.DEFAULT

after: android.intent.category.APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS

```
using var unityClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
using AndroidJavaObject currentActivityObject = unityClass.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
string packageName = currentActivityObject.Call<string>("getPackageName");
using var uriClass = new AndroidJavaClass("android.net.Uri");
using AndroidJavaObject uriObject = uriClass.CallStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("fromParts", "package", packageName, null);
using var intentObject = new AndroidJavaObject("android.content.Intent", "android.settings.APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS", uriObject);
intentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("addCategory", "android.intent.category.DEFAULT");
intentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("setFlags", 0x10000000);
currentActivityObject.Call("startActivity", intentObject);
```

Answer (score 1):

(Remove ACTION_)changed：android.settings.SETTINGS

Comment: although this may answer OP's question please conceder adding some more details and explanations to your answer